# How to list filenames within a folder based on a pattern supplied?

Tags: scripting, grep

I'm trying to find a command that will list all files in a folder containing a keyword that is inputted.

I've tried `grep -l` but it will not list anything

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for the quick response. I did use the -R flag but it shows the filenames as well as inside the files. I only want the former.

Comment: @jimmij - I want to type a word and have all filenames containing that word listed. Just the filenames. Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ls` command is used for listing files.
The shell gives you many options to list files matching a pattern, for example:

- List all files starting with "a": `ls a*`
- List all files ending with ".txt": `ls *.txt`
- List all files starting with "x" and ending with ".sh": `ls x*.sh`

There are many more interesting patterns.
To learn more, read `man bash`.
You can search in `man bash` by pressing the "/" key,
and enter the text "Pattern Matching" and press enter to jump to the relevant section.

Comment: Taking your example, How would i list all files with "a" within them ?

Comment: If you want to be absolutely sure to do the right thing, then use `-d` with `ls` to not list the _contents_ of any directory matching the pattern.  Also, when the pattern starts with `*`, use `--` to delimit it from the options, just in case there is one or several filenames starting with a dash. I.e., use `ls -d -- *.txt`, `ls -d a*`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
find /path/to/folder -type f -name "*key*"
```

The above command will search for files in all subdirectories. To search for files only in current directory (not subdirectories) use following command:

```
find /path/to/folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*key*"
```

*Above commands are specific only to bash shell*

Comment: not sure, but you might want `-maxdepth 1` *(which is GNU specific, I think)* as this will traverse any subtrees as written. It isn't perfectly clear, but I, at least, would not usually say *files in a folder* and mean that they should be recursively listed.

Comment: @mikeserv is may answer more **clear** now ?

Comment: By *not clear* I was referring to the question, not your answer. Your answer was clear enough to me, I just wasn't sure it was what was wanted,

Answer (score 0):

```
set ./*keyword*
[ -e "$1" ] || shift
printf "${1+%s\n}" "$@"
```

Will print you a list of all files in the current directory containing `*keyword*` *(which do not begin with `.`)*. More than that, though, it sets the shell's positional array to filenames. And so if these files exist they can be referenced singly in `"$1"` and `"$2"` and so on and their total count is in `"$#"`.